# Patch container in overlays

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

I have use case to add some library (agent) base on the environment

```
├───k8s
│   ├───base
│   ├───modules
│   │   └───someagent
│   └───overlays
│       └───local
```

This agent basically is a container that will communicate with the main container that I define in the base.

Can someone advice how to define in kustomization.yaml in local? I have tried with patchesStrategicMerge, but it doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: Would you like to add another container alongside the primary one via patch?

Comment: Yes. this is the goal that I would like to achieve

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you are trying to add a second (sidecar) container to an existing Pod. Since it's pretty rare to run standalone Pods I will give an example patch for a deployment but it can easily be changed to other Kinds:

```yaml
patches:
  - target:
      kind: Deployment
      name: myDeploymend
    patch: |-
      - op: add
        path: /spec/template/spec/containers/-
        value:
          # Put your container definition here. For example:
          name: myAgent
          image: ...
          command: ...
          args: ...
          env: ...
```